# USB card reader - controller errors

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

A Windows 10 64 bit system has a USB card reader that creates six "phantom drives" in Disk Manager and Device Manager. These are seen as \Device\Hardkisk4\DR4 to \Device\Hardkisk9\DR9. 
The card reader seems to work, but the Windows System log is filled with error messages even when there is no media inserted in the reader. Messages look like 
`The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk7\DR7` with numbers from DR3 through DR9.

Drivers are generic Microsoft - disk.sys, EhStorClass.sys, both 10.0.10586.

How can I solve the problem and eliminate the errors?

(As a humorous side note, the Event Viewer has an "Event Log Online Help for this event" function.  It takes you to a page on microsoft.com with nothing but MS advertisements. Nice....)

Comment: The card reader is Thermaltake AC0031 "Extreme Speed 3.0 Plus USB3.0 Multi-Card Reader"

Answer (score 0):

If a system reports six drives, then the particular USB mass storage device (which is fully described by OP as "**a USB card reader**") **does report** that it can have six independent removable volumes, all at once. Solution to the problem is not to use the "**a USB Card reader**" that reports that goofy thing.

ADDITION: As per clarification from OP, the "a USB card reader" appears to be some design by a freshman in USB. It looks like a USB compound device (USB hub with embedded controllers) with five media card interfaces/slots, plus a e-SATA port, total six mass-storage devices (MS Slot, CF Slot, SD Slot,Extreme Slot, Micro SD Slot, and M2 Port). Apparently the device declares all six devices as active LUNs, so the system reports them as such, even if no media is inserted. What else is done wrongly in this device would require lengthy investigation for conformance to USB class specifications, so the Windows log will continue to report errors, unless the device is replaced with a corrected one. I would suggest to contact Thermaltake with all your compaints, maybe they have some "filter driver" that swaps the errors under a rug. The Thermaltake idea is right about a big 3.5" bay reader, but the implementation apparently sucks.